# Which Alfresco REST API requires which authentication method?

Tags: rest, authentication, alfresco, alfresco-share

Can someone explain how authentication works in the Alfresco REST apis please? It appears that sometimes I cannot use basic as I get a format error (odd) (and have to prepend the username and password to the request); sometimes I have to use OAuth (for example create-site needs this apparently and certainly doesn't allow Basic authentication.

Could someone detail what is required for which API? Is it different between the share and repo tiers? Ultimately, and I don't think this is an open question as this is not about what's appropriate but what is required to get the GET, POST, PUT, DELETE requests working, so no opinions please, just facts :-) (and then I won't get (rightly) told off for asking an open ended question)

Answer (score 1):

You can do authentication through ticket.

Hit ticket API with username passsword and it will return you ticket from alfresco

Login webscript:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/login?u=username&pw=password
```

For all subsequent call you can append that ticket to API url for authentication.

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/<rest of the part of api>?alf_ticket=TICKET_bdbd0697d81a40f782ba8b54615abad21dc663fd
```

TICKET_xxxxxx is the ticket returned from first call and it is appended in second call.

Comment: Ok, that's a good start. But I'd rather not pass the username and password over as plaintext. Does Alfresco support a way of not doing this?

Comment: Enable ssl, then send it over https so it's not in the clear?